# In this question, I need to remove the duplicate elements of the linked list. But it is generating error in some of the test cases

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

In this question, I need to remove the duplicate elements of the linked list. But it is generating error in some of the test cases(to be specific in those cases where the duplicate element occurs at the end of the linked list). Can someone help me figure out the error?

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist)
{
    if(llist==NULL)
    return NULL;
    
    SinglyLinkedListNode* curr=llist;
    while(curr!=NULL && curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode* temp=curr;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp!=NULL && temp->next->data==curr->data)
            {
                SinglyLinkedListNode* nodetodelete=temp->next;
                temp->next=temp->next->next;
                delete(nodetodelete);
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return llist;
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't use `NULL` in modern C++, use `nullptr`.

Comment: `if(temp!=NULL` is always true.

Comment: What testcase gives the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
```

Say temp points to the second last node and the last node is a duplicate then

```
if(temp!=NULL && temp->next->data==curr->data)
```

is true and you delete the node:

```
temp->next=temp->next->next;
```

Since `temp` is the second last node `temp->next` is the last node so this sets `temp->next` to nullptr. You then do:

```
temp=temp->next;
```

so `temp` is nullptr and the next instruction is

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
```